# Using Parcel.js w/ Handlebars.js and <img> not loading

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, parceljs

I am working on my handlebars.js skills and have come across an interesting issue.  I am using Parcel.js to bundle my project.  One of my templates has an image key that has the link to the image in my project folder to display with all the characters.  My issue is that when the template compiles the image does not display, only the alt tag info.  Here is my Handlebars template:

```js
<script id="character-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
      {{#each this}}
      <div class="characters">
        {{#if image}}
        <div class="character-image">
          <img src="{{image}}" alt="picture of {{name}}">
        </div>
        {{/if}}
        <div class="character-info">
          <h3>{{name}} {{#if rank}} <span class="rank">({{rank}})</span></h3>{{/if}}
          {{#if team}}
          <p>Team: {{team}}</p>
          {{/if}}
        </div>
      </div>
      {{/each}}
    </script>
```

As i stated all the other info compiles perfect but the image src link.  I have tried using {{{image}}}, ./images/{{image}} and inside the key i have tried the same "image": "./images/image.jpg" and all other possible combinations between the template and key.  I can see in the console message that a GET request is made to the localhost/image.jpg but it never displays.  If i put a http link in the image key it displays that image and if i use an  tag outside the template the images display as well.  I know this is something related to how Parcel is building but have no idea how to fix this and since its just a small project for my portfolio I'd rather keep the images in a the project folder.  Can i accomplish this feat or do I have no choice but to host the photos else where?